# How to avoid if statements in method which gets Optional arguments

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, spring-restcontroller

How to avoid if statements when we have service method with Optional arguments? Below is example. At this moment only 3 arguments are Optional and I must have many if statements. Does exists any design pattern which solve this problem?

```
public List<Order> getForHotelOrders(Long hotelId, Optional<LocalDate> fromDate, Optional<LocalDate> toDate, Optional<List<String>> paymentTypes) {
    List<Order> orders;
    if (fromDate.isPresent() && toDate.isPresent()) {
        if (paymentTypes.isPresent()) {
            orders = orderRepository.getForHotel(hotelId, fromDate.get(), toDate.get(), paymentTypes.get());
        } else {
            orders = orderRepository.getForHotel(hotelId, fromDate.get(), toDate.get(), Arrays.asList("CASH", "CARD"));
        }
    } else {
        if (paymentTypes.isPresent()) {
            orders = orderRepository.getForHotel(hotelId, paymentTypes.get());
        } else {
            orders = orderRepository.getForHotel(hotelId, Arrays.asList("CASH", "CARD"));
        }

    }
    return orders;
}
```

Comment: If this code is actually working this question might be better suited for https://codereview.stackexchange.com. And you might want to read this blog post: http://blog.jhades.org/java-8-how-to-use-optional/ because using optional method parameters does not look like a good idea. Basically, methods should only _return_ optionals.

Comment: Also: It might be great to see documentation for the `getForHotel()` method.  For example: What happens if `fromDate` and `toDate` are `null`. Are those arguments ignored? If so, you could simplify this code a lot. Also: Create a constant for `Arrays.asList("CASH", "CARD")`.

Comment: There are two interesting links concerning this. This is a bug concerning better API documentation for optionals: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8167981 and this is a diff with the changes: http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~smarks/reviews/8167981/webrev.0/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/Optional.java.cdiff.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `orElse`

```
static final List<String> CASH_CARD = Arrays.asList("CASH", "CARD");

public List<Order> getForHotelOrders(Long hotelId, 
                                     Optional<LocalDate> fromDate, 
                                     Optional<LocalDate> toDate, 
                                     Optional<List<String>> paymentTypes) {
    List<String> paymentTypes2 = paymentTypes.orElse(CASH_CARD);
    return fromDate.isPresent() && toDate.isPresent() 
       ? orderRepository.getForHotel(hotelId, fromDate.get(), toDate.get(), paymentTypes2)
       : orderRepository.getForHotel(hotelId, paymentTypes);
}
```

or

```
public List<Order> getForHotelOrders(long hotelId, 
                                     Optional<LocalDate> fromDate, 
                                     Optional<LocalDate> toDate, 
                                     Optional<List<String>> paymentTypes) {
    return orderRepository.getForHotel(hotelId, 
                                       fromDate.orElse(LocalDate.MIN),
                                       toDate.orElse(LocalDate.MAX),
                                       paymentTypes.orElse(CASH_CARD));
}
```

BTW: If you are avoiding `null` values I would make `hotelId` either a `long` or a `OptionalLong`. Having a nullable `Long` seems inconsistent.

Comment: Yes. it's looks fine but should I use Optional as argument or not?

Comment: @DamianU You should use it if it makes your solution clearer and easier to understand to you. Only you can determine that.

Answer (score 1):

Can use orElse(default), to overcome multiple if else...

```
public List<Order> getForHotelOrders(Long hotelId, Optional<LocalDate> fromDate, Optional<LocalDate> toDate, Optional<List<String>> paymentTypes) {
    List<Order> orders;
    LocalDate defaultDate = LocalDate.now();
    orders = orderRepository.getForHotel(hotelId, fromDate.orElse(defaultDate), toDate.orElse(defaultDate), paymentTypes.orElse(Arrays.asList("CASH", "CARD")));
    return orders;
}
```